# remove ? and = from url in php

Tags: php

I have a url like:-
`<a href="category.php?category=<?php echo $categry_slug ?>"></a>`

I want to make it like
`<a href="category.php/<?php echo $category_slug ?>"></a>`

this is what i have tried
`<a href="category.php/<?php echo $category_slug ?>"></a>`
this is what i want

and how will retrieve the categry_slug from the url on categry page which displays the products of the category
please can anyone help?
The products are displayed using the get method

Comment: If you use Apache as a web server then you can do this through [a .htaccess rewrite rule](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html). Are you using Apache?

Comment: You can try to learn any PHP frameworks such as Laravel or Slim4 for lightweight. These frameworks handle url pattern perfectly. Else, url rewriting is your choice.